# beamer pause across columns

Tags: beamer

I have my current project looks like this
[image]

But I want the right column to be always on the slide ignoring the `\pause` command.
How can I do that

```latex
\begin{frame}{Encode the original information}
    \begin{columns}[T] % align columns
        \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
            \begin{table}
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    \textcolor{blue}{DB} & \textcolor{red}{00} & \textcolor{red}{00} & \textcolor{brown}{08} & \textcolor{orange}{F0} & \textcolor{cyan}{FF} & \textcolor{cyan}{FF} & \textcolor{cyan}{FF} \\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}
                \pause
            \end{table}

            $\rightarrow$ \textcolor{blue}{100 }\textcolor{red}{101 101 }\textcolor{brown}{110} \textcolor{orange}{111} \textcolor{cyan}{0 0 0}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}

            \begin{table}
                \begin{tabular}{c|c}
                    \hline
                    $a_i$ & $c_i$ \\
                    \hline
                    FF    & 0     \\
                    DB    & 100   \\
                    00    & 101   \\
                    08    & 110   \\
                    F0    & 111   \\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}
            \end{table}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Note that you should always provide a compilable MWE that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use beamer overlays:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}{Encode the original information}
    \begin{columns}[T] % align columns
        \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
            \begin{table}
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    \textcolor{blue}{DB} & \textcolor{red}{00} & \textcolor{red}{00} & \textcolor{brown}{08} & \textcolor{orange}{F0} & \textcolor{cyan}{FF} & \textcolor{cyan}{FF} & \textcolor{cyan}{FF} \\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}
            \end{table}

            \only<2->{$\rightarrow$ \textcolor{blue}{100 }\textcolor{red}{101 101 }\textcolor{brown}{110} \textcolor{orange}{111} \textcolor{cyan}{0 0 0}}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}

            \begin{table}
                \begin{tabular}{c|c}
                    \hline
                    $a_i$ & $c_i$ \\
                    \hline
                    FF    & 0     \\
                    DB    & 100   \\
                    00    & 101   \\
                    08    & 110   \\
                    F0    & 111   \\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}
            \end{table}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I was just looking for this!

Comment: @Youknowwho You're welcome!